# Why Jackson2JsonMessageConverter convert List<String> to List<Object>

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am working on Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ , I configured a `MessageConverter( Jackson2JsonMessageConverter)` with `ObjectMapper`. if I call `convertAndSend(,,,)` method from sender class by passing `HashMap<String,Object>` then `Receiver` class `handleMessage()` method successfully got the message of Type `HashMap` . But the problem is , this `HashMap` contain a `List` of string as `List<String>` . When I receive this `HashMap` in `Receiver` I tried to get `List<String>` via key but it giving an error `List<Object> can't cast Object list to string list` . This is my code of `Config` class , sender class and Receiver class

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    final static String paymentQueue = "mobily-payment-queue";
    final static String mailQueue = "mobily-mail-queue";
    final static String orderQueue = "mobily-order-queue";
    final static String deductProductQueue = "mobily-deduct-product-queue";
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.host"),Integer.parseInt(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.port")));
        connectionFactory.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.user"));
        connectionFactory.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.pass"));
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean 
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() { 
        final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(); 


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
         converter.setJsonObjectMapper(mapper);
        return converter; 
     }


    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate template(MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter) {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange direct() {
        return new DirectExchange("mobily.direct");
    }

        @Bean
        public Queue paymentQueue(){
            return new Queue(paymentQueue);
        }

        @Bean
        public Queue deductProductQueue() {
            return new Queue(deductProductQueue);
        }

        @Bean
        public Queue orderQueue() {
            return new Queue(orderQueue);
        }

        @Bean
        public Queue mailQueue(){
            return new Queue(mailQueue);
        }

        @Bean
        public Binding paymentBinding(DirectExchange direct, Queue paymentQueue) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(paymentQueue).to(direct).with(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.payment.key"));
        }

        @Bean
        public Binding deductProductBinding(DirectExchange direct, Queue deductProductQueue) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(deductProductQueue).to(direct).with(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.deduct.product.key"));
        }

        @Bean
        public Binding orderBinding(DirectExchange direct, Queue orderQueue) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(orderQueue).to(direct).with(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.order.key"));
        }

        @Bean
        public Binding mailBinding(DirectExchange direct, Queue mailQueue) {
            return BindingBuilder.bind(mailQueue).to(direct).with(environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.mail.key"));
        }

        /*@Bean
        Receiver receiver() {
            return new Receiver();
        }*/

        @Bean
        PaymentReceiver paymentReceiver(){

            return new PaymentReceiver();
        }

        @Bean
        DeductProductReceiver deductProductReceiver(){

            return new DeductProductReceiver();
        }

        @Bean
        OrderReceiver orderReceiver(){
            return new OrderReceiver();
        }

        @Bean
        MailReceiver mailReceiver(){

            return new MailReceiver();
        }

        @Bean
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer deductProductContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter deductProductListenerAdapter) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(deductProductQueue);
            container.setMessageListener(deductProductListenerAdapter);
            return container;


        }

        @Bean
        MessageListenerAdapter deductProductListenerAdapter(DeductProductReceiver deductProductReceiver,MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(deductProductReceiver, jsonMessageConverter);
        }

        @Bean
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer paymentContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter paymentListenerAdapter) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(paymentQueue);
            container.setMessageListener(paymentListenerAdapter);
            return container;


        }

        @Bean
        MessageListenerAdapter paymentListenerAdapter(PaymentReceiver paymentReceiver,MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(paymentReceiver,jsonMessageConverter );
        }

        @Bean
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer orderContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter orderListenerAdapter) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(orderQueue);
            container.setMessageListener(orderListenerAdapter);
            return container;


        }

        @Bean
        MessageListenerAdapter orderListenerAdapter(OrderReceiver orderReceiver,MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(orderReceiver,jsonMessageConverter);
        }

        @Bean
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer mailContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter mailListenerAdapter) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames(mailQueue);
            container.setMessageListener(mailListenerAdapter);
            return container;


        }

        @Bean
        MessageListenerAdapter mailListenerAdapter(MailReceiver mailReceiver,MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter) {
            return new MessageListenerAdapter(mailReceiver,jsonMessageConverter);
        }




}
```

This is My sender class

```
HashMap<String, Object> mailMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
CustomerAccountUser customerAccountUser=customerAccountUserService.getCustomerAccountUserByUsername(customerAccountPayments.getCustomerName());
             ArrayList<String> emailAddress=new ArrayList<String>();
             emailAddress.add(customerAccountUser.getEmail());
 template.convertAndSend(direct.getName(),environment.getRequiredProperty("rabbitmq.mail.key"),mailMap);
```

This is My Receiver

```
public void handleMessage(HashMap<String,Object> mailMap){

    try{
        System.out.println("mail queue..................................." + mailMap);
        String s1=(String)mailMap.get("subject");
        String s2=(String)mailMap.get("body");
        List<String> list=(List<String>)mailMap.get("emailAddress");
    }
}
```

This the error

```
    e2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 - java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at com.mobily.service.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:24)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 INFO  stdout:71 -     values
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at com.mobily.customer.rabbitmq.reciever.MailReceiver.handleMessage(MailReceiver.java:27)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:387)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:298)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1358)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
2016-05-24 17:02:47 ERROR stderr:71 -   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203)`enter code here`e
```

Comment: What is the code at`com.mobily.service.EmailService.sendEmail(EmailService.java:24)` ?. Your list seems to contain not only string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unfortunately `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` can't do that for you.

It's logic is based on three message headers:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME = "__TypeId__";

public static final String DEFAULT_CONTENT_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME = "__ContentTypeId__";

public static final String DEFAULT_KEY_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME = "__KeyTypeId__";
```

So, the best what it can do is something like `HashMap<Foo, Bar>`. But it can't build the proper nested container type because there is no such an information in the message headers.

Definitely you have to do some further conversion (casting) logic downstream in your `handleMessage` code. I mean cast not to `List<String>`, but iterate and cast each item.

Although according to your sending logic:

```
ArrayList<String> emailAddress=new ArrayList<String>();
emailAddress.add(customerAccountUser.getEmail());
```

You can try to use `array` (`String[]`) instead of `List<String>`. And that should work properly, since arrays are considered as raw types, not container.

Comment: thank you : artem bilan , yes i already tried with String[] but same error . ok i will iterate one by one

Comment: Any joy?... similar issue haunting me the last 24 hours